# Intellij - navigate to type parameter declaration from symbol

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ I can navigate to the type declaration of a symbol using `Ctrl+Shift+left click`, or `Ctrl+Shift+B` (see [IntelliJ Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/navigating-to-declaration-or-type-declaration-of-a-symbol.html)).

But suppose I have a symbol of type `Option[MyType]`. How can I navigate, via a series of keyboard shortcuts and/or mouse clicks, to the class where MyType is declared?

Comment: Is this about IntelliJ on windows or mac?

Comment: Linux specifically although it shouldn't matter, except for the exact keyboard shortcuts

Comment: In OS X holding down the Command Key (aka Apple Key) and then left mouse click on the Type takes you to the type definition. Is that what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have this case

```
val xOpt = someMethodReturningAnOption
```

and so have nothing to ctrl+click on to navigate to the class.  And the short cut you use, takes you to the Option.  Which is not that useful.

I don't know if it's possible to do in 1 shortcut in intellij 14.  What I tend to do is

step 1: Alt+enter on the variable - select "add type annotation".  This converts it to something like this.

```
val xOpt: Option[String] = someMethodReturningAnOption
```

Step 2: Ctrl+Click on the String Or whatever it is.

Step 3: Once I'm done, Ctrl+tab to go back to my original class (Or ctrl+shift+backspace to last edited location).  And undo (Ctrl+Z :)

Its a bit laborious, so a 1 step shortcut would be great to find out.

(FYI: These are my shortcuts used on my linux box )